# php delete unverified users after certain amount of time mysql

Tags: php, mysql

So I was wondering if there was a way to delete unverified users from my database after 24 hours of not being verified. So in my database there is a verified column that is 0 for unverified and 1 for verified. (My verification method is them clicking a link from an email I send them). I dont want spam users slowing down my database so I was wondering if there was a way to do this. Here is some demo code that I thought might help explain what I am talking about.

```
<?php
    if($verified === "0"){
       $sql="DELETE FROM users WHERE userid='$id'";
       // In 24 hours if verified still does not equal 1 they get deleted
       mysql_query($sql)
    }

?>
```

Comment: Yes, via `cron` jobs on Linux, or a Scheduled Task on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you should approach this by deleting the users.  Instead, maintain the time when you sent the email and use this to create an `IsDeleted` flag:

```
create view v_table as
    select t.*, ( EmailSentDateTime <= (date(now()) - interval 1 day) ) as IsDeleted
    from table t;
```

Or:

```
create view v_actives as
    select t.*
    from table t
    where EmailSentDateTime >= (date(now()) - interval 1 day);
```

You can then periodically delete the deleted records:

```
delete from table t
    where EmailSentDateTime <= (date(now()) - interval 1 day);
```

You can schedule this during a period when there is little active (perhaps Sunday morning).  You won't have to worry about deletes competing with other activities, if you schedule it well.  And, you won't have to worry about users "accidentally" remaining active, just because a job wasn't called exactly on schedule.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via Cron (if on *nix) or Tasks on Windows.

Sometimes on shared hosting you don't have access to either in which case you can execute a script every time your user accesses some part of your site (eg: logs in, or some not so frequent page) then query the DB for unverified people who have not verified for over x hours/days.

Then the logical step:
Delete all those who have not verified for X hours days.

This is not as efficient as running a cron every X hours, because the CRON/Task would run exactly (for example) 12am everyday so depending on how often your script runs, it could run the script every minute or every X days - but it would still get the job done.

If you don't want to run your main script and query the DB every X minutes/seconds etc you could create a textfile and store the last checked time there.
When someone visits your page, do a check on the textfile's date/time, if more than 24hrs have passed since you checked... run your check/delete script.